# Android Activity or Service for mathematical calculations?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a simple tip calculator to get into Android programming. I have created the main activity but I have a question. Should I do the actual calculations in the Activity, or should I have another service class that I bind the activity to that does the calculations for total and splitting and sub total, etc? Is there an advantage to doing the calculations in the service and passing the results back to the activity? Is that how it should be done?

I'm used to the whole MVC setup it seems with Android the Activity is the view and controller

Comment: How many people do you normally go to a restaurant with?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the calculations won't take very long you can do them in the main thread. However, lets assume you had a calculation that took a while -- it would be worth your while to look into AsyncTask and this post on [Painless Threading from Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).  You wouldn't want to use a service for this -- a service is more of something that sits in the background for things like notifications and alarms.